# How much will this unconventional approach hurt my RoR application's performance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

**This question is purely conceptual, it does not include any code.**

I am building an app with a single User model. I would like to give users the freedom to choose from 3 different site styles. These styles will affect other components of the UX, including a Message model and messages controller.

I am thinking the best way to go about this is to give each user a "style" column, and based on which site style they choose, either save the value as a string or an integer into the users table.

I have concocted a way to use the same Message model and messages controller, and the same actions inside the messages controller, for all three of the different types of users. Within each of the actions of my messages controller, I would basically start off by querying for which "style" attribute the current user has in their corresponding database row. Based on the three possible "styles", I could then use an if-else or a switch statement to complete the right thing inside of the controller action, depending on the current user's style, including rendering a "style"-specific template rather than the default view template.

Is there a better way to go about accomplishing this? Is it completely discouraged altogether? Am I better off just creating 3 different messages controllers, would that be more RoR conventional and less damaging to the performance of the app?

How catastrophic would it be for the performance of my app if I were to follow this approach with the actions of my messages controller and maybe even two more controllers?

*Thanks in advance for any insight anyone can give me :)*

Comment: Can these changes be achieved purely through css?  That would be the cleanest approach by far since your application logic and view files would be identical in all cases.

Comment: Have you also considered using a style choice cookie to dictate the CSS to be loaded? It'll probably be a lot cleaner and avoid you having unnecessary columns in your User table

Comment: @MaxWilliams Essentially, yes. So would it be terrible to query for the current user's "style" value in every action of the relevant controllers, and then telling the action to render the correct view? Or is that not as harmful as I'm thinking it will be?

Comment: What changes in the controller and Model based on this? The UX part using specific layout templates makes perfect sense to me but I am not sure I understand the need to change controller or model behavior as well.

Comment: @ZubatMan It sounds like a possibility. What would happen in this scenario if the user cleared their cookies? I'd prefer not to have to set a default style to be loaded upon the absence of the style cookie, and then have the user choose again.

Comment: @engineersmnky Sorry, I probably shouldn't have mentioned the model as it isn't actually relevant. The controller is where the changes are. Lets take the show action of the messages controller, for instance. Based on which style a user chooses, I would like to render a different view for the show action. The different views display different amounts of data. In one view, I may only display one instance variable, and in another view I may display five instance variables. So its the choice of whether or not a branching statement inside the action of ONE controller is the best way to go.

Comment: I think the best bet here would be to provide an example (Maybe the show method you mentioned) so that we can get a better understanding. The performance suffering probably has more to do with the "style" the user choices than the switching in the controller since some "styles" load more than others.

Comment: MY MAIN QUESTION, in this situation and others like it, is it better for the performance of my application to create three separate controllers for each type of user? Or to use one controller but break down each action into three different possibilities based on checking for the current user's relevant attribute?

Comment: @engineersmnky I don't have any code yet, I haven't started writing anything yet before I figured out if it was a better approach to create three different controllers or to use one controller. Do you have any opinion about whether I should use three different controllers or one controller with each action broken down into 3 possible outcomes?

Comment: @engineersmnky Here's an example: For one of the three styles, when  that user loads the application (root) I would like for the display to show nothing other than the number of unread messages, with a link to messages#index. For another of the three styles, when the user loads the application (root) I would like for the display to have a dashboard look to it, with unread messages making up only part of the overall view. Obviously this requires different instance variables and querying inside of the controller. Is one controller the best route, or is three different controllers the best?

Comment: My opinion would be based on implementation. Can you provide a sudo example? I would be inclined to say that a single Controller would be sufficient but depending on how you intend to implement this and how many "styles" you intend on implementing this could start to smell. Always remember *" premature optimization is the root of all evil"*

Comment: @engineersmnky Haha good advice. Any thoughts on my example above?

Comment: @Parker this approach isn't conventional, but if you handle it with a simple field on the User table then it won't cause any noticeable performance loss.

Comment: @engineersmnky * I forgot to mention, the dashboard view would include instance variables of different models as well, other than Message objects.

Comment: @ZubatMan Thank you for the advice! Much appreciated!!!!

Comment: I would create a `before_filter` or `before_action` (depending on rails version) that would set the appropriate instance variables and then just render the correct template in the controller action

Comment: @engineersmnky Thank you.. Answered my question. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: I think that performance isn't going to be the issue:  maintainability is.  Ie you run the risk of making your code really complicated and confusing and causing yourself a lot of headaches.  That's why keeping it all confined to one area, eg css, makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done very similar things with little-to-no performance impact. As long as the changes are purely HTML/CSS/JavaScript this can be easily accomplished with a working knowledge of the Rails Asset Pipeline and a single column in the database. You'll end up hitting more if-statements in your views, but those handful of boolean expressions will have a negligible effect.

Just make very sure that your alternate view styles don't affect your Controller or the Models themselves (save any methods and validations pertaining to your new column in the User table).

Be sure to dish out unique scripts and stylesheets based upon which style the user has selected (it would be *woefully* inefficient to load a single stylesheet and dynamically change classes to use certain elements, for instance. Instead you'd want to choose which stylesheet to include based upon the user's selected style, and do the same for scripts).

If you have any specific questions about implementing this, feel free to inquire further. In the mean time [this will prove to be an important read](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html), if you are not already familiar with the material.

Comment: Thanks Connor. Very encouraging answer and I'm glad to hear you've done it before.